# PHP - remove specific text from element in XML file

Tags: php, export

My goal here is to remove "origin-" from the URL in the  of a child element in my sitemap.xml file.

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
    <loc>
    http://origin-www.customURL.com
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2017-03-02</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.0</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
    <loc>
    http://origin-www.customURL.com/11/2013/
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2017-03-02</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.0</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
    <loc>
    http://origin-www.customURL.comshopper-oxblood/11/2013/
    </loc>
    <lastmod>2017-03-02</lastmod>
    <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
    <priority>0.0</priority>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

The PHP code i'm using is failing to run the foreach loop and is outputting the file with no changes made.

This is the PHP code i'm using in an attempt to pull the  element and use "str_replace" to remove "origin-":

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file("sitemap.xml");

foreach ( $xml->urlset->url->loc as $URL )
{
        $incorrectTextURL = array("origin-");
        $onlyconsonants = str_replace($incorrectTextURL, "", $URL);
}
echo $xml->asXml();
?>
```

I know i'm doing something wrong here, the 'foreach' statement keeps failing and no changes to file.

Appreciate any insight

Thank you,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Try passing $URL by reference in your foreach statement, i.e. `&$URL` and doing like so:

```
foreach ( $xml->urlset->url->loc as &$URL )
{
        $incorrectTextURL = array("origin-");
        $URL = str_replace($incorrectTextURL, "", $URL);
}
```

Currently you are looping through your foreach but not modifying the actual xml nodeValue

Comment: Appreciate your insight, does make sense but it does seem i'm running into the same error.

Getting the following error:

PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in remove_text_from_url.php on line 5

line being referenced is the "foreach" line -> foreach ( $xml->urlset->url->loc as $URL )

Comment: Apologize I didn't catch &+$URL in foreach recommendation, doesn't change much unfortunately as once added i'm getting a different error in relation to the added character:PHP Fatal error:  An iterator cannot be used with foreach

Comment: What version of PHP are you on? In newer versions of PHP (5.6+ I believe) you can pass by reference, assuming your error is because you're on 5.3.x

Comment: Good call, on 5.3 as of now but we are in the process of upgrading to PHP7.  Need to upgrade our magento platform first.  Any recommendation to resolve this issue in php5.3?  Thanks!